# Multidimensional arrays in SWIG for Java

Tags: java, swig

I'm working on an university project, to translate some C code into Java.
I have a simple C struct

```
typedef struct  {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} Point2D;
```

and another one with a bi-dimensional array

```
typdef struct {
    char name[256];
    Point2d surfacePoints[1024][1024];
    double coefs[7][7];
} Surface;
```

I need to get an equivalent Surface class in Java with a setter/getter of the following form:

```
public class Surface    {
.....
    public void setSurfacePoints( Point2D arg[][]);
    public Point2D arg[][] getSurfacePoints();

    public double[][] getCoefs() {
        return coefs;
    }
    public void setCoefs(double[][] coefs) {
        this.coefs = coefs;
    }   
}
```

Needless to say, I get some SWIG_pointers classes in Java.
I tried with JAVA_ARRAYSOFCLASSES but it works only for uni-dimensional arrays - they worked very well.
The C code cannot be changed, please advise on the possible solutions/examples for such multidimensional arrays.
Thank you,
Andrew.